# How do I change what the option pane "OK" button does when clicked?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Say you have something like this....

```
public class ActionEvents {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Whatever");
    }
}
```

This should pop up a dialog with the message "Whatever" and an OK button. Can I add an `ActionListener` to this OK button? Is there a way I can change what it does when it's clicked?

Comment: Why do you want an ActionListener attached to this button? What action do you want to take when it is pressed?

Comment: This will help you, see this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/extendsJDialogtocreateyourowndialog.htm) of a custom dialog.

Comment: What is it you want to do when the okay button is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK showing OK / Cancel buttons, then use a JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog and respond to the value returned if it represents JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int optionType = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION;
  int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
  int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Whatever",
        "Whatever Fun", optionType, messageType);
  if (value == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
     System.out.println("OK pressed");
  }
}
```

Otherwise you could use the JOptionPane.showOptionsDialog to show just the OK button:

```
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JOptionPaneFun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int optionType = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION;
      int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
      int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Whatever",
            "Whatever Fun", optionType, messageType);
      if (value == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         System.out.println("OK pressed");
      }

      String message = "Whatever";
      String title = "JOptionPane Fun";
      Icon icon = null;

      Object[] options = { "OK" };
      Object initialValue = options[0];
      int anotherValue = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message, title,
            optionType, messageType, icon, options, initialValue);
      if (anotherValue >= 0 && initialValue.equals(options[anotherValue])) {
         System.out.println("OK Pressed Again");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can add action listner on it and you can open other popup window with it

Comment: you have to create custome dialog box by extending JDialog class

Comment: @Jainik Bakaraniya please make an example with code.

Comment: *"please make an example with code."*  Please understand that SO is not your personal code generation factory!